# SQL - basic SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to create this structure in sql (as a result of SELECT statement):

[image]

I'm trying to do it by using this query:

```
SELECT "Name" AS School, (SELECT 20 AS "1", 50 AS "2", 90 AS "3") AS Age;
```

But it doesn't work, error: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`. Is it possible to create something like this using only select statements?

Comment: You may consider doing this in your application code rather than doing in SQL.

Comment: You can't select 3 column as a select column it should be only one. Value.

Comment: Columns have only one name in SQL.

Comment: You have two options : select each value in a separate query. Second option : change query to select "name" as School , age.* From ( select 20. ... )

Answer (score 2):

That sort of *formatting* is not possible in `SQL` but this is possible

```
SELECT 'Name' AS School, 20 AS `Age1`, 50 AS `Age2`, 90 AS `Age3`
```

Comment: That's not what OP wanted at all. see the posted pic in question

Comment: Yeah and so commented since in such case it shouldn't be posted as answer in first place

Comment: @Rahul - Its just an alternative. IMO nothing wrong in posting alternatives

Comment: @Rahul, he knows that. The first sentence in his answer says you can't do that in SQL. And he is right.  The Op wants two rows in the column header, the first with two columns, and the second with four columns, formatted to have the first column aligned with the first column of the first row, and the other three aligned with the second column of the first row.  You can't do that in SQL.  This should be done in client code. Did you read the question?

Comment: Plus one for sql drama